# Gem Recaptcha where should I specified the site key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I am trying to add gem recaptcha to my app but I got this error `No site key specified`. There is no answer in stack overflow solve mine.

Here is my codes
in gem file

```
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
```

in the question new form

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
              <%= f.text_field :first_name,:required => true  ,placeholder: "First Name"%>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
              <%= f.text_field :last_name,placeholder: "Last Name" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          
            <%= f.text_field :email ,:required => true ,placeholder: "Email"%>

            <%= f.text_area :description ,:required => true ,placeholder: "Questions or Comments",rows: "4" ,cols: "50"%><br>
            <%= recaptcha_tags %>
            <%= f.submit "SEND My Message" ,class: "btn btn-danger" %>
          <% end %>
```

in question controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_question, only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @questions = Question.order("updated_at DESC")
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_attributes)
    if verify_recaptcha(model: @user) && @question.save
      ContactMailer.message_send(@question).deliver
      redirect_to new_question_path, notice: "Thank you... Your message was created successfully."
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Please correct the form"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @question=Question.new 
  end

  def destroy
    if @question.destroy
      redirect_to questions_path, notice: "Message deleted successfully."
    else
      redirect_to question_path, error: "We had trouble deleting."
    end
  end

  private

  def question_attributes
    question_attributes = params.require(:question).permit([:first_name,:last_name,:email, :description])
  end

   def find_question
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

recaptch.env inside the root file

```
export RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY= xxxxxxxxxx
export RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY= xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## config/initializers/recaptcha.rb:

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key = XXXX
  config.secret_key = XXX
end
```

Comment: restart the server for changes in `config` to be available